# Magento 2.3 site cookie not set store wise

Tags: magento2

We have a multi-store site in magento 2.3
But when we move from one store to another at that time cookie not set for different store.
So category not open.
if we add '/?___store=xyz' in the category then open link proper.
Anyone help to solve this issue.

Comment: cookies are set against a domain or sub domain.  You would need to give me details

Comment: how do you set the cookie?

Comment: We set cookie from "Admin > Store > Configuration > General > Web > Default Cookie Settings".

Comment: We don't found our store name in 'Site frond end > inspect element > Application > Storage > Cookie > site name > Here our store code note found when we change store'